# VScode doesn't autocomplete variables in custom snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to turn on the autocompletion in custom-made snippets in VSCode?
I create my snippets in `javascriptreact.json`

```
  "importReact": {
     "prefix": "import-stateless",
     "body": ["import React from 'react';"],
     "description": "import React statement"
  },

  "consolelog": {
     "prefix": "import-stateless",
     "body": ["console.log($1);"]
  }
```

and use in my_file.js:

```
import | from '|'
...
const variable = '';
console.log( | );
...
```

The problem is:
when I type ***rea*** in import statement or ***varia***  in console.log - VSCode doesn't propose finish my word as ***react*** or ***variable***
It's problem with custom snippets only, because while manual typing
 `import React from 'r` it autocompletes the word ***react***;

[image: see hows it work]

Thanks

Comment: See "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Mark Thanks for your help! 
To make work autocomplete in snippets put in settings.json put the suggested line

`"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false`

[the source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50776)

Comment: Thank you for this. It's been bugging me ever since I started using vscode. Can't imagine who would ever want to use this default functionality...

Comment: I put the suggested line but its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out myself and it's really simple.

The issue is just a matter of the cursor status and making sure it's it's set to the final cursor position.

So anywhere you want to be able to use auto-complete for variables, you just add `$0` to that spot when you create the snippet, as that denotes the final cursor position: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_tabstops.

```
"Print to console": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "clg",
    "body": ["console.log($0);"],
    "description": "Log output to console"
  }
```

Unlike the prior suggestion, what this does is actually put your cursor there, so you don't need to move your cursor back into the parentheses after the call.

Happy coding!